# Javascript: why is my global variable undefined after assignment in a function?

Tags: javascript

I am starting to code in javascript, and come across this very basic issue:

My code is:

```
function get_cdq_contour(data) {
console.log(data[0].geom.geometry.coordinates) // correct value
cdq_perimeter = data[0].geom.geometry.coordinates;
console.log(cdq_perimeter) // correct value
}

const mapRequest = new Request("some_json_file.json");
let cdq_perimeter = {}
            
fetch(mapRequest)
.then((response) => response.json())
.then((data) => get_cdq_contour(data))
.catch(console.error);

console.log(cdq_perimeter); // undefined
```

where `data[0].geom.geometry.coordinates` is an [Array(145)], and `cdq_perimeter` shows the correct value in the console.log inside the function, but is undefined at the end of the process.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Because the console.log that is undefined runs before the fetch has finished.

Comment: See also [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23667086/215552)

Comment: Thank you very much. I had read about this point but was not expecting to come across it in my first days of coding.